# How do I amend this VBA so it runs when a specific worksheet is selected?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA written. Essentially what it does is; I've used 'Define Range' ("Test") on a few cells in a worksheet. The VBA makes sure that whenever the workbook is opened, it automatically zooms in to fit that range. Right now, I think it only triggers when the workbook is opened, and it gives an error message if that worksheet is not selected when the workbook is opened. Now, I would like it to run *only* if the specific worksheet is selected. I've literally copied it from someone else so don't really know how I would amend this...

Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Range("Test").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Zoom & Scroll To Cell When Worksheet Is Activated...

- ... and if the worksheet is active when the workbook is opened.
- It is assumed that the range is of *Workbook scope*.

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Const WorksheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    If ActiveSheet.Name = WorksheetName Then SelectMyRange
End Sub
```

**Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1...**

- ... where `Sheet1` is the code name i.e. the name not in parentheses, e.g. `Sheet1(Data)`, seen in the `VBE Project Explorer` window.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    SelectMyRange
End Sub
```

**Standard Module, e.g. `Module1`...**

- ... created by using `Insert Module`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SelectMyRange()
    Const RangeName As String = "Test"
    With Range(RangeName)
        .Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
        Application.Goto .Cells(1), True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's worked perfectly, thanks!
One more question though. I can't copy and paste any longer? Any idea why?

Comment: I don't know what that means, but it should have nothing to do with the code. Best ask another question describing what it means in more detail and sharing this code and the code where the issue occurs.